# watsonxlangchain package can not be installed?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, package

from watsonxlangchain import LangchainInterface
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'watsonxlangchain'

pip install watsonxlangchain
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement watsonxlangchain (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for watsonxlangchain

Answer (score 0):

`pip` cannot find this package because watsonxlangchain is not a valid Python package available on PyPI.

[image]